# Teams - keep format toolbar always visible?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there any way to have the format toolbar for Teams messages, always visible? I use it very frequently and having to find and click the button every time is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer (as of 2023-07-14) appears to be that it's not possible, and Teams will always forget your formatting bar state every time you open a new chat or switch between chats. There's an active feedback item here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/134a71e0-657d-ed11-a81b-000d3ae32cd0